# Does new instance from AMI generated from EBS snapshots require initialization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I understand that EBS volumes that are restored from snapshots need to be [initialized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html).

Let's say I [create an AMI from an EBS snapshot(s)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#creating-launching-ami-from-snapshot).

When I launch a new instance using that AMI, will I need to [initialize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html) each volume before I get consistent latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an instance from AMI which has EBS based volumes as storage, your instance creates new volume from this volume and continues with launch.

When you use snapshots as source to launch your instance, AWS need to pull these snapshots and write it to volume and then continue with the launch. In this case, pull storage blocks from S3 and write to volume will be the latency some users want to avoid. This is the case where pre-warming is suggested by AWS.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html), "New EBS volumes receive their maximum performance the moment that they are available and do not require initialization (formerly known as pre-warming)". When I start an instance, even with EBS backed storage, no pre-warming is required. I'm trying to understand if/when the pre-warming happens in the case of an AMI created from EBS-snapshots

Comment: @tkwargs a "new" EBS volume means a new **blank** EBS volume.  Not a volume from a snapshot.

Comment: @kosa you are mistaken on some of your terminology.  EC2 instances are *always* created from an AMI.  There are instance store-backed AMIs and there are EBS-backed AMIs.  EBS-backed AMIs have one or more associated EBS *snapshots*, which lead to the first-touch penalties on the EBS volumes created from those snapshots... the volume contents that instance-store AMIs use are called *bundles*, not snapshots.